# Null Context when using Dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using dagger for the first time trying to inject context into repository to load assets. I get this error however

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()'
    on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:92)
    at myJSONLoader.getJsonAsset(myJSONLoader.kt:11)
    at repository.myRepository.getData(myRepository.kt:32)
    at presenter.myPresenter.getData(myPresenter.kt:28)
    at view.myFragment.onViewCreated(myFragment.kt:51)
```

Context doesn't appear to be null but when debugging I see that mBase is null. How do I fix this?

MyApp.kt

```
class myApp : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {

@Inject
lateinit var androidInjector : DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .application(this)
        .appModule(AppModule(this))
        .build()
        .inject(this)
}

override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector

}
```

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
AndroidInjectionModule::class,
AppModule::class,
ActivityModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application): Builder
    fun appModule(appModule: AppModule): Builder
    fun build(): AppComponent
}
fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
fun inject(instance: myApp)
fun inject(repository: myRepository)
fun inject(presenter: myPresenter)
}
```

AppModule.kt

```
@Module
class AppModule(private val app: Application) {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideContext(): Context = app

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideMyRepository(): myContract.Repository = myRepository(app)
}
```

Repository.kt

```
class myRepository @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) : myContract.Repository {
    private fun inject() {
    DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .application(myApp())
        .appModule(AppModule(myApp()))
        .build().inject(this)
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.23'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.23'// if you use the support libraries
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.23'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23'
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
```

I've had no problem injecting the repository into the presenter. It's injecting context into the repository.

**Edit:** I've already added the app name to android manifest and tried calling app.applicationcontext instead of app in AppModule

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more about Dagger2 architecture. I invite you my Dagger2 sample [project](https://github.com/Emusko/DaggerApplication) example application for creating new Dagger2 application.

You do not have to register your application as Dagger application inside Repository class. Try to initialize it in BaseApplication class and made it your application class in the manifest.

By the way, you want context but return 'app' and it is Application class.

Comment: I've actually already done those parts. I added them to my post. And I've tried app.applicationContext but that doesn't work either

Comment: Wrong thing is you are making

class myRepository @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) : myContract.Repository {
    private fun inject() {
    DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .application(myApp())
        .appModule(AppModule(myApp()))
        .build().inject(this)
    }
}

this in your repository class. Do it in your Application class

Comment: Can you provide example of how I would inject context like how you did in your project?

Comment: The same way as you did in your project, But with app.context